# Mysql: Update table with count from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table like:

```
`url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cnturl` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

'url' contains some urls. In 'cnturl' I want to store how many times the same url is inside the table (yes, it's redundant, I'm doing this for speed reasons).

So to update these values I need something like:

```
UPDATE urltable 
SET cnturl=(
    SELECT COUNT(t.id) FROM urltable AS t WHERE t.url=urltable.url
 );
```

But this gives me the error:
You can't specify target table 'urltable ' for update in FROM clause

I tried as well:

```
UPDATE urltable 
  INNER JOIN (  
  SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, url FROM urltable
  ) t 
  ON t.url=urltable.url 
SET urltable.cnturl = t.cnt;
```

But this gives just wrong results (some counts are NULL while others are the count of all records).

I tried as well:

```
UPDATE urltable SET cnturl =
  (SELECT t.cnt FROM 
      (SELECT COUNT(t.id) AS cnt, url FROM urltable) t 
   WHERE t.url=urltable.url)
```

But this gives the same wrong results (some counts are NULL while others are the count of all records).

I guess it should be more something like this:

```
UPDATE urltable 
  INNER JOIN (  
  SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, url FROM urltable t
  WHERE t.url=urltable.url;
  ) t 
  SET urltable.cnturl = t.cnt;
```

But this ends up with: Unknown column 'urltable.url' in 'where clause'.

I couldn't find any other solutions for this. Any other ideas?

Comment: Speed reasons? Are you sure?

Comment: So you have the same `url` many times in the table and you want to update all its rows with the count number? And you will be updating this many rows each time new row will be added? That will be really slow...

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
UPDATE urltable 
   INNER JOIN (  
   SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(url),0) as cnt, url FROM urltable
   GROUP BY url
   ) t 
   ON t.url=urltable.url 
SET urltable.cnturl = t.cnt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
UPDATE urltable SET cnturl = 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM urltable) t 
WHERE t.url=urltable.url);
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53683/1)